# How can I convert numbers to currency format in android

Tags: android

I want to show my numbers in money format and separate digits like the example below:

1000 -----> 1,000

10000 -----> 10,000

100000 -----> 100,000

1000000 -----> 1,000,000

Thanks

Answer (score 81):

Another approach :

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));

format.format(1000000);
```

This way, it's displaying `1 000 000 €` or `1,000,000 €`, depending on device currency's display settings

Comment: this java code when converted to kotlin now requires min 24 API and `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` annotation for lower APIs

Comment: The correct approach

Answer (score 50):

You need to use a number formatter, like so:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
double myNumber = 1000000;
String formattedNumber = formatter.format(myNumber);
//formattedNumber is equal to 1,000,000
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 20):

```
double number = 1000000000.0;
String COUNTRY = "US";
String LANGUAGE = "en";
String str = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale(LANGUAGE, COUNTRY)).format(number);

//str = $1,000,000,000.00
```

Answer (score 17):

Currency formatter.

```
    public static String currencyFormat(String amount) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.00");
        return formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(amount));
    }
```

Comment: nice, had forgot how to do it, gives me complete control

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
int number = 1000000000;
String str = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(number);
//str = 1,000,000,000
```

Answer (score 8):

This Method gives you the exact output which you need:

```
public String currencyFormatter(String num) {
    double m = Double.parseDouble(num);
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###");
    return formatter.format(m);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try the following solution:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_result)).setText(format.format(result));
```

The class will return a formatter for the device default currency.

You can refer to this link for more information:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: Good option but beware of the device that has different Locale.

Comment: Add this: `format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));` or whatever your currency is. And for Local currency it will be: `format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(list.get(0).getPriceCurrencyCode()));` where `list.get(0).getPriceCurrencyCode()` comes from your app pricing.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a kotlin Extension that converts a Double to a Currency(Nigerian Naira)

```
fun Double.toRidePrice():String{
    val format: NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    format.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    format.currency = Currency.getInstance("NGN")

    return format.format(this.roundToInt())
}
```

Comment: For Nigerian Naira, another way to convert is  to call the getCurrencyInstance and parse the language and NG for Nigeria.

NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "NG")).format(it)

Answer (score 4):

#### Updated 2022 answer

Try this snippet. It formats a number in string complete with the currency & setting fractional digits.

```java
/**
     * Formats amount in string to human-readable amount (separated with commas
     * & prepends currency symbol)
     *
     * @param amount The amount to format in String
     * @return The formatted amount complete with separators & currency symbol added
     */
    public static String formatCurrency(String amount) {
        String formattedAmount = amount;
        try {
            if (amount == null || amount.isEmpty())
                throw new Exception("Amount is null/empty");
            Double amountInDouble = Double.parseDouble(amount);
            NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
            numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            formattedAmount = numberFormat.format(amountInDouble);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return formattedAmount;
        }
        return formattedAmount;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a Formatter class
For eg:

```
String s = (String.format("%,d", 1000000)).replace(',', ' ');
```

Look into:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 2):

The way that I do this in our app is this:

```
amount.addTextChangedListener(new CurrencyTextWatcher(amount));
```

And the `CurrencyTextWatcher` is this:

```
public class CurrencyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

private EditText ed;
private String lastText;
private boolean bDel = false;
private boolean bInsert = false;
private int pos;

public CurrencyTextWatcher(EditText ed) {
    this.ed = ed;
}

public static String getStringWithSeparator(long value) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);
    String f = formatter.format(value);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    bDel = false;
    bInsert = false;
    if (before == 1 && count == 0) {
        bDel = true;
        pos = start;
    } else if (before == 0 && count == 1) {
        bInsert = true;
        pos = start;
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    lastText = s.toString();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    ed.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String text = s.toString();
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if ((text.charAt(i) >= 0x30 && text.charAt(i) <= 0x39) || text.charAt(i) == '.' || text.charAt(i) == ',')
            sb.append(text.charAt(i));
    }
    if (!sb.toString().equals(s.toString())) {
        bDel = bInsert = false;
    }
    String newText = getFormattedString(sb.toString());
    s.clear();
    s.append(newText);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(this);

    if (bDel) {
        int idx = pos;
        if (lastText.length() - 1 > newText.length())
            idx--; // if one , is removed
        if (idx < 0)
            idx = 0;
        ed.setSelection(idx);
    } else if (bInsert) {
        int idx = pos + 1;
        if (lastText.length() + 1 < newText.length())
            idx++; // if one , is added
        if (idx > newText.length())
            idx = newText.length();
        ed.setSelection(idx);
    }
}

private String getFormattedString(String text) {
    String res = "";
    try {
        String temp = text.replace(",", "");
        long part1;
        String part2 = "";
        int dotIndex = temp.indexOf(".");
        if (dotIndex >= 0) {
            part1 = Long.parseLong(temp.substring(0, dotIndex));
            if (dotIndex + 1 <= temp.length()) {
                part2 = temp.substring(dotIndex + 1).trim().replace(".", "").replace(",", "");
            }
        } else
            part1 = Long.parseLong(temp);

        res = getStringWithSeparator(part1);
        if (part2.length() > 0)
            res += "." + part2;
        else if (dotIndex >= 0)
            res += ".";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now if you add this watcher to your `EditText`, as soon as user enter his number, the watcher decides whether it needs separator or not.

Comment: your implementation code can be support arabic or persian numbers?

Comment: Yes it supports both.

Answer (score 2):

i used this code for my project and it works:

```
   EditText edt_account_amount = findViewById(R.id.edt_account_amount);
   edt_account_amount.addTextChangedListener(new DigitFormatWatcher(edt_account_amount));
```

and defined class:

```
    public class NDigitCardFormatWatcher implements TextWatcher {

EditText et_filed;

String processed = "";


public NDigitCardFormatWatcher(EditText et_filed) {
    this.et_filed = et_filed;
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    String initial = editable.toString();

    if (et_filed == null) return;
    if (initial.isEmpty()) return;
    String cleanString = initial.replace(",", "");

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###");

    double myNumber = new Double(cleanString);

    processed = formatter.format(myNumber);

    //Remove the listener
    et_filed.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    //Assign processed text
    et_filed.setText(processed);

    try {
        et_filed.setSelection(processed.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    //Give back the listener
    et_filed.addTextChangedListener(this);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
private val currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(LOCALE_AUS).configure()

private fun NumberFormat.configure() = apply {
    maximumFractionDigits = 2
    minimumFractionDigits = 2
}

fun Number.asCurrency(): String {
    return currencyFormatter.format(this)
}
```

And then just use as

```
val x = 100000.234
x.asCurrency()
```

Answer (score 1):

One another helpful extension function

```
fun Long.moneyType(): String {
    val s = this.toString()
    var result: String = s[s.length - 1].toString()
    for (i in 1 until s.length) {
        result = if (i % 3 == 0) {
            "${s[s.length - i - 1]} $result"
        } else {
            s[s.length - i - 1] + result
        }
    }
    return "$result USD"
}
```

You can also use Int as a parent of extention.

**There is an updated version of the code**

```
fun String.moneyType(): String {
    return this
        .reversed()
        .chunked(3)
        .joinToString(" ")
        .reversed()
}
```

To use this you can take another extension function

```
fun Long.moneyType(): String {
    return this.toString().moneyType() + " USD"
}
```

everthing is ready to use. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have the value stored in a `String` like me, which was coming from the server like **"$20000.00"**.
You can do something like this in **Kotlin** *(JetpackCompose)*:

```
@Composable
fun PrizeAmount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    prize: String,
) 
{
    val currencyFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("en", "US"))
    val text = currencyFormat.format(prize.substringAfter("$").toDouble())
    ...
}
```

> Output: "$20,000.00"

Answer (score 0):

```
fun formatToCurrency(editText: EditText) {
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        try {
            // Remove any non-numeric characters
            val cleanString = s.toString().replace(Regex("[^\\d]"), "")

            val parsed = cleanString.toDouble()
            val formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(parsed / 100)

            // Update the EditText with the formatted currency
            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this)
            editText.setText(formatted)
            editText.setSelection(formatted.length)
            editText.addTextChangedListener(this)
        } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
})}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve this with this small simple library.
https://github.com/jpvs0101/Currencyfy

Just pass any number, then it will return formatted string, just like that.

```
currencyfy (500000.78); // $ 500,000.78  //default

currencyfy (500000.78, false); // $ 500,001 // hide fraction (will round off automatically!)

currencyfy (500000.78, false, false); // 500,001 // hide fraction & currency symbol

currencyfy (new Locale("en", "in"), 500000.78); // ₹ 5,00,000.78 // custom locale
```

It compatible with all versions of Android including older versions!

Comment: I see no benefits using this over NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().

Comment: Why not? Did you ever add space between $ symbol and number? This lib automatically do that. Reduces code. More 'on the fly' customization with simple call.

Comment: @X.Y. Did you read the answer? As it says there, "It compatible with all versions of Android including older versions!" Whereas `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance` requires API level 24

Comment: I probably didn't read too carefully about the older Android version, but I did check out the code on Github, it did not pass my bar of using it. Good luck with using a library that's not maintained for 4 years and only a few stars. There's a reason why no one's using it. If I had to support 24 and below I'd just write a bunch of if elses.

Comment: @X.Y. Okay I just looked at the code on GitHub and it's using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance` internally, so I agree with you it's no better than just using that method. This library would also require API 24. I wish there was a compatible alternative, because if-else taking into account all locales and currency oddities would be a huge piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale("ES", "es")).format(number)`

Answer (score -1):

here is a kotlin version to Format Currency, here i'm getting an argument from another fragment from an input Field then it will be set in the textView in the main Fragment

```
fun formatArgumentCurrency(argument : String, textView: TextView) {

        val valueText = requireArguments().get(argument).toString()
        val dec = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
        val number = java.lang.Double.valueOf(valueText)
        val value = dec.format(number)
        val currency = Currency.getInstance("USD")
        val symbol = currency.symbol
        textView.text = String.format("$symbol$value","%.2f" )

    }
```