# how can i create pattern number for edittext in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I want it to be 1,000,000    and not 1000000 when the user enters a number in edit text.
type number is double .

var amount_loan = edt_amount_layout_2.text.toString().toDouble()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert numbers to currency format in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45592109/how-can-i-convert-numbers-to-currency-format-in-android)

Comment: use text watcher, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265406/16177121

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Automatically add thousand separators as number is input in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338445/how-to-automatically-add-thousand-separators-as-number-is-input-in-edittext)